# How to animate this "infinity" svg path to fade in using gsap or any similar animation tool/library that will work in react.js?

Tags: html, reactjs, animation, svg, gsap

Here is the infinity svg path that I am referring to:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M367.5 0.5C434.971 0.5 490 55.529 490 123C490 190.539 435.039 245.5 367.5 245.5C316.23 245.5 285.062 217.227 261 182.5C268.178 170.947 274.053 159.641 280 148.703C301.465 184.182 325.527 210.5 367.5 210.5C415.762 210.5 455 171.262 455 123C455 74.465 416.035 35.5 367.5 35.5C339.199 35.5 321.221 45.617 304.609 62.844C287.998 80.07 273.984 104.953 259.766 131.203C245.547 157.453 231.123 185.07 210 207.219C188.877 229.367 159.756 245.5 122.5 245.5C55.0293 245.5 0 190.471 0 123C0 55.461 54.9609 0.5 122.5 0.5C173.496 0.5 204.869 28.025 229 62C221.822 73.348 215.4 84.24 209.453 95.109C188.125 60.656 164.336 35.5 122.5 35.5C74.2383 35.5 35 74.738 35 123C35 171.535 73.9648 210.5 122.5 210.5C150.322 210.5 167.822 200.383 184.297 183.156C200.771 165.93 214.854 141.047 229.141 114.797C243.428 88.547 258.125 60.93 279.453 38.781C300.781 16.633 329.902 0.5 367.5 0.5Z"/>
</svg>
```

[and this is how I'd like to animate it by slowly fading it in from start to end positions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH7lI.png)

To be honest I am new to gsap so I have no idea what I'm doing but I tried this code and it fades in the entire svg path all at once, which is not what I'm aiming for.

```js
import gsap from "gsap";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.set(["#infinity"], { autoAlpha: 0 });
    const infinityTimeline = gsap.timeline();
    infinityTimeline.to("#infinity", {
      autoAlpha: 1,
      duration: 1.5,
      ease: "Power1.easeInOut",
    });

    const masterTimeline = gsap.timeline();
    masterTimeline.add(infinityTimeline);
    masterTimeline.play();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <svg width="490" height="526" viewBox="0 0 490 526">
        <path
          id="infinity"
          d="M367.5 111.5C434.971 111.5 490 166.529 490 234C490 301.539 435.039 356.5 367.5 356.5C316.23 356.5 285.062 328.227 261 293.5C268.178 281.947 274.053 270.641 280 259.703C301.465 295.182 325.527 321.5 367.5 321.5C415.762 321.5 455 282.262 455 234C455 185.465 416.035 146.5 367.5 146.5C339.199 146.5 321.221 156.617 304.609 173.844C287.998 191.07 273.984 215.953 259.766 242.203C245.547 268.453 231.123 296.07 210 318.219C188.877 340.367 159.756 356.5 122.5 356.5C55.0293 356.5 0 301.471 0 234C0 166.461 54.9609 111.5 122.5 111.5C173.496 111.5 204.869 139.025 229 173C221.822 184.348 215.4 195.24 209.453 206.109C188.125 171.656 164.336 146.5 122.5 146.5C74.2383 146.5 35 185.738 35 234C35 282.535 73.9648 321.5 122.5 321.5C150.322 321.5 167.822 311.383 184.297 294.156C200.771 276.93 214.854 252.047 229.141 225.797C243.428 199.547 258.125 171.93 279.453 149.781C300.781 127.633 329.902 111.5 367.5 111.5Z"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to explain what the animation should look like. I get that is should "run around" following the arrows, but should it be like a gradient that fades out, different colors etc.?

Comment: @chrwahl Sorry my question wasn't clear enough. I would like it to be one solid color fading in from the start position and follow the arrows around the infinity symbol like you said until it reaches the end position in the image attached. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Just to clarify, by "fade in" do you mean that the leading edge of the animation starts white/transparent, and fades in to black?  And the leading edge moves along the path from start to finish?

Comment: If so, then effectively you would need to animate a gradient that runs the length of your path. Unfortunately SVG does not support gradients lthat follow the path.  You would need to fake the effect. For example by converting your path to a series of little rectangles that are positioned along the path. Then fade those in sequentially.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Yes exactly. Well, I have another question to follow up on what you said: Is there a way to take this single path that makes up the entire infinity symbol and evenly split it into x number of paths, and then I can animate/fade in one after the other till I get to the end?

Comment: @BG My first suggestion would be to try fiddling around with dash patterns.  If you apply a dash pattern, then convert that object to a path. Then do the same pattern again, but subtract it from your original path to get a path for all the gaps. Then split each of those two dashy paths into individual bits. Then finally, merge  everything  
 Hopefully you can make sense of that description.